# JQuery, Rails and Json: Unexpected token o

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json

I'm a beginner with a good ruby & rails knowloedge but a very limited javascript knowledge.

I'm trying to push some values in a Select2 jquery plugin instance.

I'm using this script to manage my Select:

```
$('.ajaxselect').each(function() {
    var url = $(this).data('url'); 
    var placeholder = $(this).data('placeholder'); 
    var saved = jQuery.parseJSON($(this).data('saved'));
    $(this).select2({
      minimumInputLength: 2,
      multiple: true,
      placeholder : placeholder,
      allowClear: true,
      ajax: {
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        quietMillis: 500,
        data: function (term) {
          return {
            name: term
          };
        },
        results: function (data) {
          return {results: data};
        }
      },

      formatResult: function (item, page) {
        return item.name; 
      },

      formatSelection: function (item, page) {
        return item.name; 
      },

      initSelection : function (element, callback) {
        if (saved) {
          callback(saved);
        }
      }

    });
  });
```

I have a problem with "Unexpected token o" on this line:

```
var saved = jQuery.parseJSON($(this).data('saved'));
```

In my view I'm calling this code in this way:

```
= form.input :brand_ids, label: false,          |
                  input_html:                                     |
                  {                                               |
                    class: 'ajaxselect form-control',             |
                    data: {                                       |
                      placeholder: "Scegli brand",                |
                      saved: content.brands.to_json,              |
                      url: '/admin/brands/list.json'              | 
                           },                                     |                       
                  }
```

My saved value generated in the right way: I try with pry and `content.brands.to_json` return me the rights data.

Here is my binding.pry log

```
pry(#<#<Class:0x007fc66caecd30>>)> content.brands.to_json
=> "[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Sony\"},{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"Panasonic\"}]"
```

Here is my HTML generated code

```
<input class="string optional form-control form-control form-control form-control ajaxselect form-control" data-placeholder="Scegli brand" data-saved="[{&quot;id&quot;:1,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Sony&quot;},{&quot;id&quot;:2,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Panasonic&quot;}]" data-url="/admin/brands/list.json" id="content_brand_ids" name="content[brand_ids]" type="text" value="[1, 2]">
```

Why I'm having this problem? to_json is a method provided by rails...

Comment: can you share the html sample as well

Comment: what is the value in `data-saved`

Comment: @ArunPJohny the HTML generated by my Haml code?

Comment: can you add the generated html from browser view source

Comment: I think you can just say `var saved = $(this).data('saved');` there is no need to parse it, the `data()` method will do it for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the line

```
var saved = jQuery.parseJSON($(this).data('saved'));
```

it should be

```
var saved = $(this).data('saved');
```

because [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) will do the parsing for you

Demo: [Problem](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2f3CL/2/), [Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2f3CL/)